# ISAPI Rewrite Block Requests With Keywords in Query String

Tags: isapi-rewrite, request.querystring

How can I block requests with certain keywords in the query string using ISAPI Rewrite.

i.e. lolita, model, girl etc...

Query_String Example:

pid=12263&pid=12263&sourcingName=Qxcfljaw&sourcingEmail=thebest%40hotmail.com&sourcingPhone=76513817313&sourcingQty=87&sourcingComments=What's+the+last+date+I+can+post+this+to++to+arrive+in+time+for+Christmas%3F+http%3A%2F%2Flsmagazinexl.kazeo.com+lolita+model+dads+girl++Wonder+what+was+wrong+with+the+original+sounds+so+they+had+to+replace+them+with+these+obviously+and++ridiculously+fake+ones.%0A+

Answer (score 0):

Was able to accomplish this.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*(?:nude|lolita|porn|viagra|cialis|naked|preteen).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]